# imaging processing programme

Tags: java, image, swing, image-processing, frame

I want to make like acdsee programme using java programming language. this programme have some properties, like that, it is capable of black and white image, capable of mirroring and scratch on the line. but as first step, I could only add and delete images, other steps how can I do that? do I use any libraries for that?

thank you for helping and any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many libraries available for image processing for example [here](http://code.google.com/p/java-image-scaling/) you will find a library for resizing, [here's](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/index.html) another powerful program for image processing. The usage of libraries may depend on your need. I'll give you some simple things. The easiest way to convert a color image to a gray scale image is to simply draw the color image to a gray scale BufferedImage. Code sample is below

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height,
    BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
g.drawImage(colorImage, 0, 0, null);
g.dispose();
```

There are many such examples available to you if you just search for it. 
One of the book I referred for learning about images and graphics is [here](http://filthyrichclients.org/). It is basically a rich client development tutorial. I would recommend you to go through this textbook. The first few chapters there will definitely give you some basics. [AlphaComposite](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html) is again one of the useful class. These things are very interesting with the above mentioned book.

Comment: firstly thank you for your helping. Can you give me a web site which also includes simple examples about it?

Comment: Sure, http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/45132-mirror-an-image/. THe best way is to search the google with the correct keywords like for example, mirror image in java, crop image in java and so on. IT is because you have different requirements and everything will not be available in one place. All the best with your programming.

Answer (score 1):

You could use third-party libraries as suggested by vini, but Java already contains a quite powerful API for handling 2D graphics. Doing things like scaling, mirroring, rotating, filtering (to for example blur, sharpen or convert to black and white) and compositing images in other ways are all possible with the standard API.

See [Trail: 2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some examples in this book: http://filthyrichclients.org